# PropTypes eslint error with pure render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have the following pure render component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

export const renderDropzone = ({ name, input: { onChange } }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dropzone
          name={name}
          onDrop={filesToUpload => onChange(filesToUpload)}
      />
      <button type="button" className="button">Upload</button>
    </div>
  );
};

renderDropzone.PropTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  input: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

But I am getting the following error in eslint:

```
  4:34  error  'name' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types
  4:40  error  'input' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

Comment: A static property of a stateless component is called `propTypes` with lowecase "p".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a typo:

```
renderDropzone.PropTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

should be:

```
renderDropzone.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

(lowercase 'p' on the class property)